# How to determine the origin of a thrown exception without writing a try/catch for each statement?

Tags: java

I am wondering if this is possible to do without writing a try/catch block for every single call. I want to be able to tell which method threw the exception so I can handle them differently. Consider the following two (fairly identical) methods:

```
public void setBranchID(String ID) throws NumberFormatException{
    if(ID.trim().length() != 0 && ID != null){
        try{
            branchID = Integer.parseInt(ID);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){           
            OutputFunc.printError(ex); //Prints the stack trace to console
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    else{
        branchID = null;
    }
}

public void setCashOnHand(String cash) throws NumberFormatException{
    if(cash.trim().length() != 0 && cash != null){
        try{
            cashOnHand = Double.parseDouble(cash);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            OutputFunc.printError(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    else{
        cashOnHand = null;
    }
}
```

What I want to do:

```
try{
    setBranchID(String1);
    setCashOnHand(String2);
    //Other methods
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    if(/*Exception came from setBranchID*/){
    //Code
    }
    else if(/*Exception came from setCashOnHand*/){
    //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: You can go check the stacktrace.

Comment: Create custom exception classes

Comment: If the logic for error handling depends on the execution branch, why don't you put the logic in the branch directly, instead of trying to guess afterwards?

Comment: Here the null-check is useless: `ID.trim().length() != 0 && ID != null`. If `ID` happens to be null, a `NullPointerException` will be triggered by the first check before you reach the second one.

Comment: @dotvav I wanted to ensure data coming from an SQL server is valid (which will require logging so I can check it, but not the user being notified) vs coming from the user (which will require no logging and them being notified), but I am just realizing now that that shouldn't be an issue if the database constraints are set properly. Regardless, I think it is nice for extra robustness, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev Good point, that is a logic error. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not necessarily need to create a new exception (even though its probably nicer) but you can just change the message returns from the exception :

```
public void setBranchID(String ID) throws NumberFormatException{
    if(ID.trim().length() != 0 && ID != null){
        try{
            branchID = Integer.parseInt(ID);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            OutputFunc.printError(ex); //Prints the stack trace to console
            throw new NumberFormatException("setBranchID error : " + ex    );
        }
    }
    else{
        branchID = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the exception message if it starts with the setBranchId:

```
    try{
        t.setBranchID("xxx");
        t.setCashOnHand("xxx");
        //Other methods
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        if (ex.getMessage().startsWith("setBranchID")) {
            System.out.println("error from setBranchID method");
        }
        .....
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom exception, which would have some sort of enumeration which would provide hints as to where the error took place:

```
public enum ErrorType {
        BranchId,
        CashOnHands
    }

public class MyException extends Exception {
    private ErrorType errorType;

    public MyMyException(string message, ErrorType errorType) : super(message) {
        this.errorType = errorType;
    }

    public ErrorType getErrorType() {
        return this.errorType;
    }
}
```

Then you create an exception like so: `throw new MyException(..., ErrorType.Branch)` and then, in your handling statement:

```
...
catch(MyException e) {
     switch(e.getErrorType) {
         case ErrorType.BranchId:...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this---

```
    try {
        setBranchID(String1);
       setCashOnHand(String2);          

    } catch (Exception e) {

        StackTraceElement se[] = e.getStackTrace();

        String s = se[0].toString();

        int startIndex = s.indexOf(".");

        int endIndex = s.indexOf("(");

        String newstr = s.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
```

newstr will have the name of the function that throws the exception. You can compare it and do your desired processing.

I tried it and its working fine.

I hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to write a `try` - `catch` block for every single method simply obtaining the method name directly from the stack trace like this:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public void testMethod1(){
        int x = 1/0;
    }

    public void testMethod2(){
        int x = 1/0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass c = new TestClass();

        try {
            c.testMethod2();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
        }
    }
}
```

The `main` method above prints *testMethod2*

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is quite simple, don’t re-throw and exception. But maybe you want to do this, so then probably your custom exception is the easiest way because you can enforce that it has the information about the original method. But can I just make some remarks, don’t read if not interested but please consider.

This code you have written looks very similar to the code I wrote when I first started doing GUI programming, I thought using this functionality from checked exceptions is a good idea for validating user input but it’s not. I even stuck checked exceptions in the data objects themselves, for instance in the setters of an employee class.

Eventually what you’ll find that methods, which have nothing to do with exceptions generated by methods nested deep in your control structure are having to handle exceptions or throw an exception which has nothing to do with them, soon every method in your code will be doing this, for many different exceptions.

What is the answer then? You’ll find that preventing exceptions will be your best attack. Use components which enforce the correct data, such as formatted text fields. Then in your code you can know with certainty that methods are not going to have exceptions. If you have complex validation going on, then just think about how you can design your code, look at some GUI patterns such as the MVC pattern (there are at least 2 versions of this pattern by the way). Then there are alternatives, I found returning an enumeration value then using a switch statement for each case can be a nice solution too. Or another idea is that each error message you can merely append to a string and then output as well, anything but throwing exceptions, and if you are going to throw an exception, don’t throw a checked one unless someone is going to die if you don’t.

I think it’s a fine art to know when it is a good idea to throw an exception, but shouldn’t be your first choice.